# How can I create an Express EJS project from the command line?

Tags: node.js, express

I have tried

`express -e myproject`

However this does not work as expected

Comment: "Does not work as expected"? What *does* it do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
express --help

  Usage: express [options] [path]

  Options:
    -s, --sessions           add session support
    -t, --template <engine>  add template <engine> support (jade|ejs). default=jade
    -c, --css <engine>       add stylesheet <engine> support (stylus). default=plain css
    -v, --version            output framework version
    -h, --help               output help information
```

so, do >express -t ejs [path]

Comment: As of Express 4.x, install express-generator `npm install -g express-generator` and then use `express -e myproject`

Answer (score 10):

How to install **express** from the command line using **express-generator** and use **EJS template engine**

1) Install express-generator globally("-g") if you don't have it already

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

2.1) Check available commands

```
express -h
```

Result(in express version: 4.13.4):

```
  Usage: express [options] [dir]

  Options:
-h, --help          output usage information
-V, --version       output the version number
-e, --ejs           add ejs engine support (defaults to jade)
    --hbs           add handlebars engine support
-H, --hogan         add hogan.js engine support
-c, --css <engine>  add stylesheet <engine> support (less|stylus|compass|sass) (defaults to plain css)
    --git           add .gitignore
-f, --force         force on non-empty directory
```

2.2) Generate an Express app with chosen preferences

```
express --ejs --git my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore
```

Result:

```
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/package.json
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/app.js
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/.gitignore
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/public
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/public/javascripts
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/public/images
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/public/stylesheets
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/public/stylesheets/style.css
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/routes
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/routes/index.js
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/routes/users.js
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/views
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/views/index.ejs
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/views/error.ejs
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/bin
   create : my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore/bin/www

   install dependencies:
     $ cd my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore && npm install

   run the app:
     $ DEBUG=my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore:* npm start
```

3) Navigate into the app directory and use NPM to install dependencies

```
cd my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore
npm install
```

Result:

```
+-- body-parser@1.15.2
| +-- bytes@2.4.0
| +-- content-type@1.0.2
| +-- depd@1.1.0
| +-- http-errors@1.5.0
| | +-- inherits@2.0.1
| | +-- setprototypeof@1.0.1
| | `-- statuses@1.3.0
| +-- iconv-lite@0.4.13
| +-- on-finished@2.3.0
| | `-- ee-first@1.1.1
| +-- qs@6.2.0
| +-- raw-body@2.1.7
| | `-- unpipe@1.0.0
| `-- type-is@1.6.13
|   +-- media-typer@0.3.0
|   `-- mime-types@2.1.11
|     `-- mime-db@1.23.0
+-- cookie-parser@1.4.3
| +-- cookie@0.3.1
| `-- cookie-signature@1.0.6
+-- debug@2.2.0
| `-- ms@0.7.1
+-- ejs@2.4.2
+-- express@4.13.4
| +-- accepts@1.2.13
| | `-- negotiator@0.5.3
| +-- array-flatten@1.1.1
| +-- content-disposition@0.5.1
| +-- cookie@0.1.5
| +-- escape-html@1.0.3
| +-- etag@1.7.0
| +-- finalhandler@0.4.1
| +-- fresh@0.3.0
| +-- merge-descriptors@1.0.1
| +-- methods@1.1.2
| +-- parseurl@1.3.1
| +-- path-to-regexp@0.1.7
| +-- proxy-addr@1.0.10
| | +-- forwarded@0.1.0
| | `-- ipaddr.js@1.0.5
| +-- qs@4.0.0
| +-- range-parser@1.0.3
| +-- send@0.13.1
| | +-- destroy@1.0.4
| | +-- http-errors@1.3.1
| | +-- mime@1.3.4
| | `-- statuses@1.2.1
| +-- serve-static@1.10.3
| | `-- send@0.13.2
| |   +-- http-errors@1.3.1
| |   `-- statuses@1.2.1
| +-- utils-merge@1.0.0
| `-- vary@1.0.1
+-- morgan@1.7.0
| +-- basic-auth@1.0.4
| `-- on-headers@1.0.1
`-- serve-favicon@2.3.0
```

4) Start the server

```
DEBUG=my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore:* npm start
```

Result:

```
my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore@0.0.0 start C:\Users\Marian\OneDrive\Documente\Practice\Node\express_generator_2\my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore
node ./bin/www
Sun, 31 Jul 2016 13:51:25 GMT my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore:server Listening on port 3000
```

5) See the result in the browser 
Open a browser and navigate to: **http://localhost:3000/**

The page should contain the following text:  
Express 
Welcome to Express

Comment: the newest version of of express-generator has changed the 'express --ejs --git my_app_with_ejs_and_gitignore' one to 'express --view=ejs' and this has to be done on the relevant folder

Answer (score 4):

the one that worked for me is

```
npx express-generator --view=ejs
```

no need to pre-install anything (except of nodeJS of course)

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

and then

```
express -e project-name
```

this will create a project with ejs template engine

Answer (score 3):

Just start you project with this command

```
express --view=ejs appName
```

don't forget to install **express-generator** globally by `npm install -g express-generator`

Answer (score 2):

1. Install express globally `npm install -g express`
2. In terminal, go to the directory in which you want your project to reside. If you are in the directory that you want the files to be in, just type `express`. If you want express to make a subfolder for the project, type `express appname`.
3. To install EJS, use `npm install ejs`
4. To configure EJS in your express project, you have to make sure you have the following line in your app.config function:

   ```
   app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
   ```

EDIT: As dmh2000 pointed out, you can also just do `express -t ejs`

Answer (score 2):

The option to use depends on the installed version of express (check `express -V`!)

It was changed somewhere around version 3.0.0alpha1.

It used to be: `express -t ejs`, now it is: `express -e` or `express --ejs`

Proof (from express Git repo):

```
git log -S'--ejs' # Search for the change using pickaxe
git show 29508f1 # The commit
git cat-file blob 29508f1:package.json|grep version # express version
```

Morale: NodeJS modules are moving targets, *always* check their docs, especially after updating stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Express provides a generator (see instructions below), however for a batteries included generator, you might choose my [express-no-stress](https://github.com/cdimascio/generator-express-no-stress) generator.

**Express-no-stress**

> Includes ES.next via Babel.js, structured logging with Pino, API validation and interactive documentation via Swagger, environment based config with dotenv, linting with ESLint, and Backpack powered builds.

**Install**

`npm install -g yo generator-express-no-stress`

**Generate Project**

`yo express-no-stress myapp`

**Run**

`npm run dev`

---

Or use the **Express Generator**
that can be used as follows:

**Install**

`npm install express-generator -g`

**Generate Project**

`express myapp`

Comment: You may want to read [How to offer personal open-source libraries?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/229085)

Answer (score 2):

Do the following steps:
1. Install ejs:

```
sudo npm install -g ejs
```

2. Install node express generator:

```
sudo npm install -g express-generator
```

3. Reboot the system
4. Create app with express generator:

```
express --view=ejs myApp
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the express generator installed:

```
npm install express-generator -g
```

then to start a project

```
express myproject
```

To display the help screen

```
express --h
```

I hope it helps